# How to get login attributes from a servlet/jsp

Tags: java, servlets, basic-authentication

Lately I've been working on implementing security for my web application, running on a Glassfish v3. I successfully managed to secure some resources by setting a basic authentication up like following:

```
<login-config>
<auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
<realm-name>vcards-admin</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

Now I was wondering how to get the user name introduced on the login prompt to fecth the actual data of the user. I thought there could be a session attribute to get that piece of data, but I don't know which one it is.

Am I wrong about the session attribute? Is there any other way to access that login information?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's available by [`HttpServletRequest#getUserPrincipal()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getUserPrincipal%28%29) or its shorthand [`HttpServletRequest#getRemoteUser()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRemoteUser%28%29):

```
String name = request.getUserPrincipal().getName();
// Or
String name = request.getRemoteUser();
```

Equivalently in JSP EL:

```html
${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name}
<!-- or -->
${pageContext.request.remoteUser}
```

Comment: BalusC can you explain what is the UserPrincipal and why we use it ?