# Dynamically set context-param in tomcat webapp?

Tags: xml, jsp, tomcat, web-applications

I have webapp deployed on tomcat_5.0.28, Linux.

my app is multi users and profiles (user can be admin or just simple user).

In my `web.xml` I have these lines

```
...
<web-app>
    <display-name>my-app</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>configFileName</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/my-app-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    ...
```

How to set the value of the param `configFileName` at user login according to his profile

Comment: I mean if user's profile is admin then **/WEB-INF/my-app-config-adm.xml** if simple user **/WEB-INF/my-app-config-usr.xml**

Comment: Are you getting the parameter value from within a servlet? If so why not determine the file name based on the logged in user by getting the user principal? This post may help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976921/how-to-get-login-attributes-from-a-servlet-jsp

Comment: I used `request.getRemoteUser()` to get username after user login, but one I change the `param-value` it changes for all users (not only active one).

Comment: Don't change the param value. Maybe set the param value to a template like `/WEB-INF/my-app-config-{username}.xml`. The after getting the remoteuser replace {username} with it. Now you have the path to the user's config file.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use the param value as a template

```
 <param-name>configFileName</param-name>
 <param-value>/WEB-INF/my-app-config-{username}.xml</param-value>
```

Then you jsp can be something like this

```
 String userName = request.getRemoteUser()
 String temp = context.getInitParameter("configFileName");
 String fileName = temp.replace("{username}", userName);
```