# Is pageContext.request.userPrincipal stored in session? Can I get password too?

Tags: jsp, servlets, spring-security, passwords, userprincipal

I'm learning Spring security and as I understand by using `request.getUserPrincipal()`  we could access the *name*,  we could get the name with `pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name` ,

This is my code (everything is working) :

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@page session="true"%>
<html>
    <body>
        <h5>Title : ${title}</h5>
        <h5>Message : ${message}</h5>


        <c:if test="${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name != null}">
            <h2>Hi User : ${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name}></h2> 
            <br>
        </c:if>

    </body>
</html>
```

my questions are:

1). Is this *name* on `pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name`  retrieved from session? because there's `<%@page session="true"%>` on the top of the form

2). Is it possible to retrieve the *password* also? I mean something like `pageContext.request.userPrincipal.password`, if not how I could get the password in the form?

Thank you  I really appreciate your help to get me understand this framework as I don't have enough money to buy some springs books, I'm just using some tutorials in the internet so your helps will be so much mean to me.

Comment: Why would you need the password?

Comment: Hi @BalusC, thanks for responding , I'm doing php also, usually we could check the password manually (in the bad practise approach / beginner approach) through something like if (pass == _var_from_session ), in java we could do checking itself with servlet or something with backing model , I'm just wondering if we could that but in the form instead. Or maybe I must misunderstand the purpose of *pageContext.request.userPrincipal* here

Comment: If password were wrong, there would be no logged-in user in first place.

Comment: Oh yeah that makes sense very much (my mind starts opening),thank you very much @BalusC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Is this name on pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name retrieved from session?*

No, it's retrieved from `request`, not from `session`. Under the covers, however, the security framework may store the internal identifier in the HTTP session. But this should be your least concern.

There's by the way a shorter way to retrieve the principal name.

```
${pageContext.request.remoteUser}
```

See also a.o. [How to get login attributes from a servlet/jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976921/how-to-get-login-attributes-from-a-servlet-jsp/).

---

> *because there's <%@page session="true"%> on the top of the form*

This has a different meaning and is the default already. By default, when a JSP is opened, it will implicitly create the HTTP session if not already created yet. This may not be desirable in pages which are designed to be stateless. Developers will then use `<%@page session="false"%>` to turn off implicit session creation and leave it to the servlet code. See also a.o. [Can I turn off the HttpSession in web.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255814/can-i-turn-off-the-httpsession-in-web-xml/)

---

> *Is it possible to retrieve the password also? I mean something like pageContext.request.userPrincipal.password, if not how I could get the password in the form?*

Based on the question's comments I gather that you needed it in order to validate the login. This makes no sense. If the login was not valid, there would be no logged-in user in first place.